# I have a problem when i try to bulid blender manual on linux

Tags: documentation

I am trying to build Blender manual on my Linux system but I have this problem:
[image: The problem]

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A guess: you have an old version of sphinx-build that doesn't support the `auto` argument to `-f`. Read this [sphinx-build](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html) reference. As an experiment you could try something like this at the command line,

```
$ SPHINXOPTS="-j 2 -D language=en" make html
```

which will override the default `-j` parameter (the number of parallel processes).